# How to create an aggregated RSS Feed with all the people I am following on Twitter

Tags: twitter, rss, google-reader

I am looking for a way to get an RSS-Feed that serves the same content as the main view on Twitter. I am following about 20 people at the moment and I could of course get an RSS-Feed from each of them separately, but I don't want my RSS-Reader to be cluttered with 20 Feeds if I can aggregate them into a single feed.

I don't want to maintain two different lists, the one on twitter and the one for my RSS-Feed. What I am looking for is a service that aggregates those RSS-Feeds via the list on Twitter. Or maybe Twitter offers such an RSS-Feed all by itself and I haven't been able to locate it. Any hints how I should approach this problem? I am using the Google-Reader if it makes any difference.

Comment: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/following_timeline.atom?user_id=92188039

Answer (score 0):

The simplest RSS aggregators are ones such as [rssmix](http://www.rssmix.com/), which I used a few times in the past, it's very simple.

On the other hand, there are social aggregators, such as [Waaffle](https://waaffle.com/) and [Taggbox](https://taggbox.com/), which I believe has some more comfortable and user friendly capabilities, but I've never tried them.

---

#### More options

- Simple RSS aggregators: [Comparison of feed aggregators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_feed_aggregators)
- List of some [Social media aggregators](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-Social-Media-Aggregator-I%E2%80%99d-like-to-be-able-to-read-my-friends%E2%80%99-feeds-from-Facebook-Twitter-Google+-etc-in-one-place).